# Probability that the sum of square of three numbers is divisible by $7$

Tags: probability

Given $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N},$ find probability that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is divisible by $7.$

Attempt: from given condition

$x,y,z \in \{7k+1,7k+2,7k+3,7k+4,7k+5,7k+6,7k+7\}, k\in \mathbb{N}$

I'm not able to form different cases, help me to solve it, thanks.

Comment: What are squares congruent to mod 7?

Comment: This question is incomplete. What is the distribution of $x,y,z$? Are they picked uniformly?

Comment: @Durgesh Tiwari: To make the term "probability" meaningful for this problem,  you could assume $x,y,z$ are chosen randomly and independently from the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: It's absolutely malicious to close this question because the assumed probability model is not explicitly declared.  Occam's razor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) tells us to assume that $x$, $y$, $z$ are independently uniformly distributed mod $7$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

We know that for $k\in \mathbb N $, $$k^2 \equiv 0,1,2,4 \pmod 7$$

Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

The main part of solution:

a square of an integer can be only $0,1,2,4$ modulo 7 (it can be easily checked by taking squares of $7k+i$ for $i=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ and investigating the remainder), so the sum of 3 squares is 0 mod 7 iff all of these numbers are divisible by 7 or their quadratic residues modulo 7 are $1,2,4$.