# Probability that $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ mod $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163601/probability-that-the-sum-of-square-of-three-numbers-is-divisible-by-7) on MSE asked the following:

"Given $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N},$ find probability that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is divisible by $7.$"

The OP did not declare the assumed probability model, and was duly criticised for that. On the other hand, it is only natural to assume that $x$, $y$, $z$ are independently uniformly distributed mod $7$.

A case analysis then shows that that the  probability in question is ${1\over7}$. This simple result led me to solve the same problem for the primes $p=3$, $5$, $11$, and $13$. In each case I obtained ${1\over p}$ as result. Further experiments showed that the remainder of $s=x^2+y^2+z^2$ mod $p$ is not uniformly distributed mod $p$, but that in any case the probability of $s=0$ mod $p$ is equal to ${1\over p}$ for all $p\leq107$. This leads to the following

**Conjecture.** Let the integeres $x$, $y$, $z$ be independently uniformly distributed modulo the prime $p$. Then the probability that $s:=x^2+y^2+z^2$  is divisible by $p$ is equal to ${1\over p}$.

Maybe this well known. Otherwise I'd like to see a proof.

Comment: If the conjecture is true this probably means that $w:=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is and uniformly distributed random variable in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: so far, this is part of theorem 4.12 in Charles Small, Arithmetic of Finite Fields. Alright, it is exactly theorem 4.6 on page 91, need notation....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Found it.](https://books.google.com/books?id=b9n5KJuxGBEC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=small%20arithmetic%20of%20finite%20fields%20%20%20notice%20here,%20in%20contrast%20to%20theorem%204.5&source=bl&ots=nHtZjhnCPu&sig=NtnYOgTCiEv2TujFBuX7MZZ3FZk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimltjDl7HSAhXJr1QKHSX7BA4Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=small%20arithmetic%20of%20finite%20fields%20%20%20notice%20here%2C%20in%20contrast%20to%20theor) Given odd dimension $n$ and  quadratic form
$$  f = a_1 x_1^2 + a_2 x_2^2 + \cdots + a_n x_n^2, $$
everything in a finite field with odd number of elements $q,$ the count
$$ \#\left(f = b\right) \; =  \; q^{n-1} + q^{(n-1)/2}  \; \; \chi \left( \; (-1)^{(n-1)/2} \;  b a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n\right).  $$ At the bottom of page 91 Small points out that 
$$ \#\left(f = 0\right) \; =  \; q^{n-1} .  $$
When $b \neq 0$ we need to know what $\chi$ means.

Aah. Page 86, very simple. We have finite field $F$ and element $a.$ First $\chi(0) = 0.$ If $a$ is a nonzero square, $\chi(a)=1.$ If $a$ is nonzero and not a square, $\chi(a)=-1.$

Charles Small, *Arithmetic of Finite Fields*, Theorem 4.6 on page 91,